# Dynamically changing array size in C++

Tags: c++

I need to transform an array from `{4, 2 ,5}` to `{4, 2, 5, 4, 2, 5}`. Here's my output: `{4, 2, 5, 3.21143e-322, 0, 2}`, which is obviously incorrect. But I cannot seem to figure out the issue in my logic. Perhaps another perspective can find that issue.

---

This is my code:

```
void repeatArray(double* oldArray, int size) {
    int newSize = size * 2;
    double* newArray = new double[newSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        newArray[size+i] = oldArray[i];
    }
    oldArray = newArray;
    delete [] newArray;
}

int main() {
    double* oldArray = new double[3];
    oldArray[0] = 4;
    oldArray[1] = 2;
    oldArray[2] = 5;
    repeatArray(oldArray, 3);
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
        cout << oldArray[i] << endl;
    delete []oldArray;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C++, use the STL containers, i.e. `vector<double>`. What you are writing is more C without C++...

Comment: Use the standard library, they're there for a reason

Comment: You can either return the pointer to the newly created array, or pass a reference to the oldArray and use a double pointer to access it in your function.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that merely assigning the new array to the pointer in `repeatArray()` does not change it from the outside.

What you can do in `repeatArray()` is to *return* the newly created array.

```
double* repeatArray(double* oldArray, int size) {
    int newSize = size * 2;
    double* newArray = new double[newSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        newArray[size+i] = oldArray[i];
    }
    delete [] oldArray;
    return newArray;
}
```

And in `main()`:

`oldArray = repeatArray(oldArray, 3);`

---

A probably better approach would be to use `std::vector` that is resized automatically as needed.

Comment: Although answering the question, this is really C-style coding. In modern C++, the use of `new` and `delete` are even [considered 'bad'](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-the-%E2%80%98new%E2%80%99-and-%E2%80%98delete%E2%80%99-keywords-considered-bad-in-modern-C++)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I'm required to use a void function so I can't return anything from that function.

Comment: @Hassan In that case, you can pass a reference pointer to repeatArray: `void repeatArray(double*& oldArray, int size)`. With this, changes to the pointer will **be** visible outside the method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `repeatArray` parameters are local to the function, so if you change their value, the change won't be seen past the function call. You can use a pointer to pointer `double** oldArray` to change what `oldArray` is pointing to, or return the pointer of the new array location.

However, this is `C++`, where you can use STL containers. Your code would become much more simple and readable.

```
void repeat( std::vector<double>& numbers ) {
   // Reserve rellocates the vector if there is not enough space
   // otherwise, the iterators first and last could be invalidated.
   numbers.reserve( numbers.size() * 2 );

   auto first = numbers.begin();
   auto last = numbers.end();
   std::copy( first, last, std::back_inserter(numbers) );
}

int main() {
   std::vector<double> nums({4, 2, 5});
   repeat(nums);
   for( double num : nums ) {
      std::cout << num << '\n';
   }
   return 0;
}
```

`std::vector` takes care of your allocation, reallocation and copy of the elements, and the deallocation of the resources it makes use.

Comment: That was really simultaneously. :-)

Comment: Oh boy, I almost fell for that one too. Can you spot the bug? ;)

Comment: Yes. It is not `std::fill`. My memory has betrayed me :(

Comment: Hah, I actually autocorrected that in my head while reading it, didn't notice. Not, it's more subtle!

Comment: please dont turn SO into a code writing service. At least you should explain what is wrong with OPs code

Comment: @JorgeBellón ok, I'll drop it: the `back_inserter` might cause the vector to reallocate, invalidating both `first` and `last` and causing UB on the next iteration. You need to `reserve` first to make sure that doesn't happen :)

Comment: Although the compiler will do it for you, I would not create the variables `first` and `last`. Just write `std::copy(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::back_inserter(numbers) );`. It is very readable and maintainable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is required from me that I use this approach and not vectors, even though the latter is much easier and more suitable for this task. I'll try passing a pointer to a pointer and hopefully it works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said `C++`, I suggest you use a proper container, e.g. `std::vector`.

If you don't have a very good reason to do your own memory management, than you should avoid using `new` and `delete`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new) for an elaborated explanation.

Using templates enhances the possibility to reuse the `repeat` function with other types than `double`.

Thus, your code is reduced to the following and is easier to read.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> repeat(const std::vector<T>& originalVec) {
    auto repeatedVec = originalVec;
    repeatedVec.insert(repeatedVec.end(), originalVec.begin(), originalVec.end());

    return repeatedVec;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<double> oldArray {4,2,5};

    const auto newArray = repeat(oldArray);

    for (const auto item : newArray) {
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please dont turn SO into a code writing service. At least you should explain what is wrong with OPs code

Comment: @user463035818 I disagree with your statement. The OP clearly does not yet know how to use STL. A good example could help there. BTW. You could post your comment to almost every answer on SO... So many times people give code examples.

Comment: it does not help OP to understand what is wrong with their code. Next time OP encounters similar problem they will post a similar question again and you will again post working code? this isnt the SO I know

Comment: ..btw I never said that an example using a vector is useless, it just doesnt answer the question

Comment: @user463035818 you could as well state that Minas Mina's answer is 'bad', as he also give the solution in code. Who says the OP will not be back with a similar question anyhow ;)

Comment: minas answer starts with "The problem is .." explaining what is wrong with OPs code, that is what is imho missing in yours. Nevermind, I cannot convince you but I can give your answer a downvote, case closed ;)